# Swap function keys at OS runtime

Tags: windows, windows-10, laptop

I have an Alienware R2 anw17-7493slv and I can't figure out how to change FN keys to multimedia keys at runtime. I know there is a option in BIOS to do this, but I want to do this at runtime.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can actually do this exactly as you want per se, but I **can** think of a way for you to achieve the same functionality using a third-party program called [AutoHotkey](https://autohotkey.com). It's basically a program for remapping keys and key sequences, but it also supports some rudimentary programming.

Assuming your multimedia keys actually generate keys and don't activate some other functionality (e.g. running a command or something), you could make a script that flips your function keys and your multimedia keys only when a Boolean variable is set. Then assign a key or shortcut to flip the value of this variable.

Here is an example for a script that flips the functionality of <kbd>F2</kbd> and the media <kbd>Play / Pause</kbd> keys only when the variable is set, with <kbd>Scroll Lock</kbd> toggling the variable:

```
FlipKeys := false

~ScrollLock::FlipKeys := !FlipKeys

#If FlipKeys

F2::Media_Play_Pause
Media_Play_Pause::F2

#If
```

There's a neat added feature here that if <kbd>Scroll Lock</kbd> is off when you start the script (for example if you run it when Windows starts) then the keys are flipped only when <kbd>Scroll Lock</kbd> is on. =)

This would basically work for replacing any two keys conditionally (you can add more replacements inside the same `#If` statement the same way I did). When you hold down the <kbd>Fn</kbd> key and press one of your function keys, the keyboard actually sends a different key code to the system, so it's like you physically pressed a different key. That's why I don't think you can do this outside the BIOS settings, but it's also why this idea should work.

You can find a list of all the keys supported by AutoHotkey [here](https://autohotkey.com/docs/KeyList.htm).